# How much CO2 is produced by wood biomass under complete combustion?

Tags: combustion, industrial-engineering, wood, emissions

If I have a one tonne (equivalent to 1.167 m<sup>3</sup>) of residual wood product used in a suspension burner at 3% moisture. The wood consists of a mixture of softwood by-products. How much CO<sub>2</sub> would be produced under complete combustion?

Comment: This has the feel of homework.  Show us some effort and we will help, but we do not do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What woods? that makes a difference.

Comment: Figure out the carbon content of the wood in kg. You know (or can look up) the atomic mass of carbon and oxygen so you can work out how to scale up the result from C to CO$_2$.

Comment: Thanks @StainlessSteelRat. but it is actually for my MSc. I am doing an LCA on organic fertilizers and one manufacturer uses a suspension burner to emit heat and dry manure...

Comment: @SolarMik  The wood is OSB residual. They utilize a mixture of softwood from Eastern Canada - ash, pine. l am having difficulty understanding what I need to find. I think its the density of the dry OSB.

Comment: Hi @Transistor I knot the carbon content is roughly 50%. but I think that is at wet weight.  Because the wood is very dry at  3% mc, wouldn't this mean there would be  more carbon ??? This is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Let's clarify some things: 3% moisture by weight? volume? 1000 kg is the gross weight? net weight? something else?

Comment: Its 3% moisture by weight. 1000kg is the gross weight.

Comment: If you start with 1000 kg of wood that has 3% by weight water, that means you have 970 kg is wood that can burn. The 50% figure you stated before would apply to this mass.